# Setting UIImageView with image from cache

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview, uiimage

**I cache an image when the user logs in like this:**
This is in a `Utility.m`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:newProfilePictureData];

UIImage *mediumImage = [image thumbnailImage:280 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:0 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
UIImage *smallRoundedImage = [image thumbnailImage:64 transparentBorder:0 cornerRadius:9 interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationLow];

NSData *mediumImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mediumImage, 0.5); // using JPEG for larger pictures
NSData *smallRoundedImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallRoundedImage);
```

**Later on I would like to load the small image into an `UIImageView`:**
This is in a `UITableView` - `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.leftIcon setImage:
```

Does anyone know how I can reference the cached image?

Comment: Using the variable you assigned it to, perhaps?

Comment: [cell.leftIcon setImage:smallRoundedImage]; --- this results in an error use of unidentified identifier

Comment: any context with that, please?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question slightly. When the user logs in I call a method in the Utility.m file which stores their profile picture to cache. I then need to load the cached image again later on in the app, within a custom UITableViewCell called cell. I need to set the image view called leftIcon to this cached image

Comment: if I get this correctly, you want a global variable?

Comment: I just want to be able to used the cached image again on another imageview

Comment: that's what I'm saying, maybe a singleton or a global variable would fit (google them).

Comment: what are you suggesting a global variable for a string of the filename, or variable of the path, or a variable of the actual image?

Comment: that doesn't matter, either one does the job.

Comment: Utility is already setup as a singleton in this case

Answer (score 0):

You need something like below method in Utility.m,

```
+(NSString*)getImage {
    return smallRoundedImage;
}
```

Then use it like below,

```
[cell.leftIcon setImage:[Utility getImage]];
```

PS: This is just an example, you can make this much better based on what's your requirements!

Comment: I can load the string to the path of the image, but then I am unable to setImage to a path